# Difference between cbmanager backup and cbbackup command

Tags: backup, couchbase, database-backups

While taking my couchbase  backup I found two way in couchbase 1) cbbackup 2) cbmanager utility.
What is the deference between both. I have tried both command and working fine but cbbackup is taking more time than cbmanager command.

Please help in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In short, use CBMANAGER whenever you can.

CBMANAGER - "Designed for the Enterprise Edition, it replaces the cbbackup and cbrestore tools as the primary and recommended means of backup and restore for Enterprise customers from version 4.5 and above"

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/backup-restore/backup-restore.html

Comment: Okay, both are open source right? means couchbase enterprise and community? can we download from couchbase.com  and installed the same without any cost?